# VSTO - Excel - How to call range.Validation.Delete() without raising an error?

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> keys before calling `range.Validation.Delete()`, Excel shows the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

How can I prevent this error in an asynchronous method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the procedure that calls `range.Validation.Delete()`?

Comment: How are you setting the value for `range`?

Comment: Also, have you set a break point and added any watches for variables?

Comment: Hey, @aduguid, it is as simple as "range.Validation.Delete();", unfortunately. The only thing that is different is that, before calling this procedure, I press Alt + Down arrow on the keyboard. If I don't press Alt + Down before calling it, everything works fine. I think I need to find a way of knowing if Alt + Down was pressed and the Validation is been shown. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I also get the same error if I call "Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.SendKeys("{ESC}");", for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `TryCast` to cast a variable as an `Excel.Range`. Then check to see if what it equals. As well as trapping any exceptions.

```
Public Sub MyProcedure()
    Dim range As Excel.Range = Nothing
    Try
        range = TryCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection, Excel.Range) 'must cast the selection as range or errors
        If range IsNot Nothing Then
            range.Validation.Delete()
        End If

    Catch
        'your error message here

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately the range object will not be null (or Nothing in VB.NET) even if I pressed Alt + Down before calling "range.Validation.Delete();". Thanks anyway.